# Fast multithreaded random sequence in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, random

I need to use random in a multi-threaded loop, but require the same values through each loop independent of which thread is evaluating that cycle.

Without multi-threading I can do:

```
seed(1)
for (unsigned int i=0; i<100; i++){
     rand()
}
```

Within the loop each time rand() will be called it will return a new pseudo-random value. Now I want to create the same list multi-threaded.

The main reason is that I need the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers independent of the order of the loop (so more like based on 'i' within the loop).

Note: I've been going through many 'random' and 'multithreading' topics but only found solutions on how to make sure the numbers are always random, not the other way around.

**EDIT:**

The result should be as if based on a seed a random list is created. And that random list should be used within the loop with index 'i' to get the pseudo-random value. So within the loop the same random number will be at index 'i' based on the seed. (Yet there shouldn't be a single random number same throughout the loop. But the sequence should be the same for each program run. Independent of number of threads or which thread is evaluating a part of the cycle.)

It wouldn't be very efficient to create that list (non-multithreaded) and use that initialized list within the multithreaded loop. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 4):

Use any non-STDC random number generator, with a separately manageable state. I recommend this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_random.html

Comment: Note: in C++11 there is `<random>`

Comment: How would this work? Can you provide an example?

We can't just use a seperate state for each thread, because we can't assume the same thread will be doing the same cycle in the loop on the next run. Or we can't even assume that the same amount of threads will be used. Right?

Comment: Well, if you want the state to go with the thread, you can use TLS.

Comment: @MatthieuM., you should be more explicit about what you mean by your comment.

Answer (score 3):

You need a counter-based random generator, instead of a congruential one. A good document explaining how they work is here:

http://www.thesalmons.org/john/random123/papers/random123sc11.pdf